# Geometric Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

What does the parentheses mean in this problem?

$$\sum_{K=0}^4 {4\choose K} x^k y^{4-k}$$

```
4 
Sigma Symbol              (4)
                          (K) x^k y^4-k
K=0
```

> The 4 and the k are in the same parentheses but the 4 is right above the k.It's on top, not side by side.

Comment: You should try to use some markup to draw this as it appears, or even post an image. What you've posted sounds like a poor transcription of a summation series, not a logarithm.

Comment: I tried to guess what you meant.  Does it look right?

Comment: @MJD no idea if you got it right, but if we assume that some newlines were lost after the 4 and before the K=0 then you did a remarkable job of reassembling it!

Comment: @Sparr Thanks, but I think OP deserves credit for making such a thorough effort to explaining what they meant.

Comment: thanks MJD for making my OP clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol ${4\choose k}$ means "number of ways to choose $k$ objects out of $4$ objects," without taking order into account. You can read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

Comment: Thamks a lot! sorry for the mis label

Answer (score 1):

If you mean $\displaystyle\binom{4}{k}$ then this is a binomial coefficient, generally defined as $\displaystyle\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

$($for $0\leq k\leq n$, and where $n!=n\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)\cdots \;3\cdot 2\cdot 1)$

Not quite sure what your question has to do with logarithms though...